# ffmpeg converted vertically stacked .mp4 videos are not playing on windows

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to merge two videos in a vertically stacked video using the ffmpeg vstack filter.

```
ffmpeg -i movie01.avi -i movie02.avi -filter_complex vstack output.mp4
```

It works great when i play it on VLC, but Windows Media Player and some Android devices can't play the video file.

Edit: also tried with the pad and overlay:

```
ffmpeg -i movie01.avi  -i movie02.avi -filter_complex "[0:0]pad=iw:2*ih[a];[a][1:0]overlay=0:h" output.mp4
```

but still the same, it doesn't work on WMP and some Android devices.

It is weird because the two separate videos work fine on Windows and Android, but not the merged one.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should check output format of the encoded video using media info or similar utilities.

Comment: This is usually down to the pixel format or possibly codec profile.

Comment: Show the actual command line output from the command, please.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It seems some players don't support high resolutions so it is necessary to set them.

For example, stack vertically a video on 900x1080:

```
ffmpeg -i movie01.avi -i movie02.avi -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 900x1080 -filter_complex vstack output.mp4
```

Hope it helps someone! ;-)